# Spark cluster is not dynamically allocating resources to jobs

Tags: apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, ambari

The cluster is HDInsight 4.0 and has 250 GB RAM and 75 VCores.

I am running only one job and the cluster is always allocating 66 GB, 7 VCores and 7 Containers to the job even though we have 250 GB and 75 VCores available for use. This is not particular to one job. I have ran 3 different jobs and all have this issue. when I run 3 jobs in parallel , the cluster is still allocating 66 GB RAM to each job. Looks like there is some static setting configured.

[image]

The following is the queue setup

[image]

I am using a tool called Talend(ETL tool similar to informatica) where I have a GUI to create a job . The tool is eclipse based and below is the code generated for spark configuration. This is then given to LIVY for submission in the cluster.

```
sparkConfiguration.set("spark.hadoop.talendStudioTimeZone", java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    sparkConfiguration.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    sparkConfiguration.set("spark.kryo.registrator", TalendKryoRegistrator.class.getName());
    sparkConfiguration.set("spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion", "true");

    tuningConf.put("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts", "1");

    tuningConf.put("spark.scheduler.mode", "FIFO");
```

This is the screen shot of spark defaults

[image]

Comment: Can you post the config values for executor cores, memory, and your dynamic allocation configuration values you're using when submitting to either livy or spark-submit?

Comment: @RonDeFreitas edited the question.

Comment: What's the num of executors and excutor cup and memory? You can check this spark UI config tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is expected as `6` execuors * `10` GB per executor memory = `60G`.

If want to use allocate more resources, try to increase exeucotr number such as `24`

Comment: As there any setting which allows spark to use as much as executors possible dynamically rather than I setting the number. For Ex. if I set -1 then spark use as much as executors possible to run in the cluster.

Comment: AFAIK, spark don't have such setting now.